# Matrix Notation Format

Tags: matrices

Can matrices be enclosed in a box or does it have to be in brackets to be correct at all. I completely enclosed a matrix with lines and got it wrong on a test because of it.Is it a hard and fast rule?

Comment: Matrices are put inside brackets or parentheses, not full boxes.

Comment: It is weird though that somebody would lessen the grade just because of that.

Comment: @Lauri Was everything marked as incorrect? If it was, as Lord Soth says, that's weird. In my opinion some people do way worse things that go unpunished (even lecturers).